# How to utilise plastic straws?

Tags: plastic

I want craft ideas because I have a heap of plastic straws that I want to use for some sort of craft. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi ! There are lot of truly amazing craft ideas available on Youtube.Like making beautiful flowers and all..Have a try on it . :)

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  The site is designed to focus on solving specific problems that have a "right answer".  Collecting project ideas isn't really a good fit (that applies to all the Stack Exchange sites).  As ASMI suggests, a good starting point is a search of sites like YouTube and Pinterest; there's tons of great ideas out there.  If you try one and run into a specific problem or question, that might make a more in-scope question for the site.  Happy crafting!

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help] to get a better understanding of how this site works and what kind of question is a good fit. We'll be happy to help you with any specific question or problem, but fishing for ideas is not really acceptable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also have some thread and a long needle, you could jump into exploring geometrical shapes:

[image]

To build them, thread three straws (or parts of them) and tie them together to build a triangle. Then add further triangles at the edges.